# Why does Git write to my files?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit, git-push

I have a few source files in a Git repo, `main.c` and some others. I use Vim to edit these files.

Say I'm editing `main.c`. I make a change, tell Vim to write-out, then switch to a terminal (without killing Vim) and commit/push. If I go back to Vim with `main.c` and try to write-out again, I receive this warning:

```
WARNING: The file has been changed since reading it!!!
Do you really want to write to it (y/n)?
```

How does committing/pushing modify my source files? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a permission issue (git changing the executable bit of the file).
Try again after `git config core.filemode false`.

The solution is simple: reopen the file with `:e filename`.
Or (if your files are save and have no current modification), run `:bufdo e`, which will make Vim reopen every buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your .gitattributes file?  Are you telling it to change the line endings?

Why don't you try doing a diff and showing us what the differences are.

Comment: I don't have a `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: How would I find the diff?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have shown that the write may be due to Git performing a line ending change, or expands configured attributes. A simple solution is to

```
:set autoread
```

in Vim, to automatically update the file (as long as you haven't changed it, which based on your use case seems unlikely).

> ```
> 'autoread' 'ar'         boolean (default off)
>         When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
>         it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
> ```